# Combining table rows into a single row (Set?)

Tags: mysql

Here's an example scenario, say that I have a social media website, such as facebook or whatever and I want to get all of a users photo ids based on their email address.

Here are the tables (Base form)

```
x_users:
    - user_id
    - user_email
    - user_pass

x_photos:
    - photo_id
    - user_id
```

How can I make it so that the results for a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM x_users 
LEFT JOIN x_photos ON x_users.user_id = x_photos.user_id 
WHERE x_users.email = '...';
```

Would return something like this: (All in a single row, atleast)

```
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | user_email |  user_pass  | user_photos |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | ...        | my-password | 1,2,3,4,5   |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Instead of:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
| user_id | user_email |  user_pass  | photo_id |
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | ...        | my-password |        1 |
|       1 | ...        | my-password |        2 |
|       1 | ...        | my-password |        3 |
|       1 | ...        | my-password |        4 |
|       1 | ...        | my-password |        5 |
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is suitable in your case:

```
SELECT user_id, user_email, user_pass, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) FROM x_photos b WHERE b.user_id=a.user_id) AS photo_ids
FROM x_users a WHERE email = '...';
```